# is there a repo where I can install flutter directly without the official website?

Tags: apt, repository, snap

I want to install flutter but couldn't find a repo in the apt nor snap package manager? is the only way just through their website? I'm asking because I want  to automatically handle the updates instead of me checking and installing it manually everytime?

Answer (score 0):

There is now a snap:
`sudo snap install flutter --classic`